# Verilog [dot] meaning?

Tags: verilog, vlsi

What does this " .depth_log2(7) " and  `.i_wclk` mean in Verilog code?

```
  asynch_fifo #(.depth_log2(7),
  .data_width(22),
  .rd_flop1_megedge(1'b1),
  ) USB2_ASYNCH_FIFO (
  .i_wclk(i_usb2_sieclockin_ip),
   );
```

I'm not able to understand what that `.depth_log2` and `.rd_flop1_megedge` means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you instantiate a module, such module might have some parameters. You can leave them at default, or you can initialize them at the values you prefer. In your example you are setting the depth at 7, the data width at 22 etc..

In general, if you have a verilog module like this:

```
module my_module
  #(    parameter P1 = 2,
        parameter P2 = 0)

  ( input               clk,
    output  reg [P1-1:0] out);
    
    // Module logic

endmodule
```

You can instantiate it with the dot notation

```
    wire         wire_clk;
    wire [2-1:0] wire_out;

    my_module #(.P1(2), 
                .P2(3) ) u0
               ( .clk(wire_clk),
                 .out(wire_out);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called instantiation. Using this "." notation you are basically saying that you want to connect a constant 7 to depth_log2 parameter of your component asynch_fifo.